# how to overrwrite css of bootstrap in laravel 5.2?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5

I am using bootstrap. I need some things of my style so i want to change it. I have a style.css file inside as Myproject/assets/css/style.css but showing no effect in home blade..

Comment: Are you loading your styles AFTER bootstrap? Also, you might need to *shudders* use `!important` as bootstrap loves that too!

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is quite simple.
Suppose you are using a bootstrap button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
```

and you want change the background color of the button to be black instead blue.
so you can write like this:

```
.btn-primary {
background-color: #000000 !important;
}
```

This will override the default background color of the Primary button.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

to avoid conflict you can add your own class and add !important to its css.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary my-btn-primary">Primary</button>
```

in css file

```
.my-btn-primary {background-color: #000000 !important;}
```

in this way there will be no problem if you use the original class of brn-primary in other page.